# DICOM VR ST with multiple value

Tags: dicom

If I read the definition of DICOM VR [ST, short text](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_6.2.html#para_c3562b1a-cde1-45ac-a612-ca53c8c15033):

> A character string that may contain one or more paragraphs. It may
>   contain the Graphic Character set and the Control Characters, CR, LF,
>   FF, and ESC. It may be padded with trailing spaces, which may be
>   ignored, but leading spaces are considered to be significant. **Data
>   Elements with this VR shall not be multi-valued** and therefore
>   character code 5CH (the BACKSLASH "\" in ISO-IR 6) may be used.

So, the data element shall not be multi-valued.

But, I found a few DICOM Tag in the dictionary that has DICOM VR=ST and DICOM VM=1-n, which is multi-valued.

For example:

> (0014,0023) CAD File Format

And few others from `(0014,...)`

So, how should I understand this? Is the DICOM VR definition wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the definition of `Short Text` is correct and the `VR` should be always 1.

The Tags 0014,0023 and 0014,0024 are retired anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where do you see that those tags are retired? Well, I only checked using 2011 Dicom Data Dictionary PS 3.6-2011 Page 16, and they are not retired there.

Comment: You can see that retired flag in the html version [http://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part06/chapter_6.html](http://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part06/chapter_6.html)